# How to highlight words in a DataGridView

Tags: c#

**Hello**

I am currently having trouble with highlighting only the found words in a dataGridView.

Here is the code I have for looking horizontal for the words.

```
        public Boolean IsForwardHoriz(String Word, int initalRow, int initalColumn)
    {
        int column = initalColumn + 1;

        if (initalColumn + Word.Length > m_GridSize)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        for (int i = 1; i < Word.Length; i++)
        {
                    if (dataGridViewpuzzle[column, initalRow].Style.BackColor.Equals(Color.White))
                    {
                        dataGridViewpuzzle[column, initalRow].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        dataGridViewpuzzle.Refresh();
                    }
                
                if (puzzlearray[column][initalRow] != Word[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And here is the Vertical.

```
   public Boolean IsDown(String Word, int initalRow, int initalColumn)
    {
        int Row = initalRow + 1;

        if (initalRow + Word.Length > m_GridSize)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < Word.Length; i++)
        {
                    if (dataGridViewpuzzle[Row, initalColumn].Style.BackColor.Equals(Color.White))
                    {
                        dataGridViewpuzzle[Row, initalColumn].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                        dataGridViewpuzzle.Refresh();
                    }
                
                if (puzzlearray[Row][initalColumn] != Word[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            
        }
        return true;

    }
```

[This is what it looks like when I run the program. I want only the words the be highlighted yellow nothing else.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWjsY.png)

If you can help me that would be very much appreciated. I just can't seem to figure it out with everything I try.

Comment: Is this WPF?  I think you need to tag this question with the UI technology that it is asking about.

Comment: Indeed : What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Also: You may have better success if you get into the habit of adding short but useful comments into the code, so you can always see what the next line(s) are meant to achieve.